# Defining a graph with both vertex cost and edge cost

Tags: graph-theory, definition

In general, a graph with cost value assigned on edges can be defined as $G=(V,E,c)$ where $c:E\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is the edge cost function. But, what about a graph with cost value assigned on both edges and vertices? Is there any formal mathematical structures to define it? Is there any source/literature that discuss about such graph?

Comment: A cost value assigned on vertices we can represent formally by the vertex cost function $c_V:V\to\Bbb R$.

Comment: @Alex, ya, I understand that. We can define the edge and vertex cost functions $c_V:V\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $c_E:E\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ at the same time. But is it legal to define that graph as $G=(V,E,c_V\cup c_U)$? If no, how should $G$ be defined?

Comment: There is no need to devise a too formalistic definition of a graph as a quadruple. It is OK to think about a graph $G=(V,E)$ endowed with two functions $c_V:V\to\Bbb R$ and $c_E:E\to\Bbb R$.